# Filter css property not working in chrome

Tags: image, css, sass

I am using filter CSS property to change the background of the svg image. It is working on desktop browsers. But when I tried it on my phone it is not working (Android Chrome).
Chrome is up to date.

```
filter: invert(1);
```

Link to the code
https://github.com/jibin2706/blog.jibin.tech/blob/d532a3ae397385a2c7821532a18b053d0609627d/src/components/colors.scss#L100

Result
The property is applied to social media images in the footer.

https://blog.jibin.tech

Comment: Don't know if it will fix it, but i'd try adding `-webkit-filter: invert(1);` as well.

Comment: It is been added by Gatsby.

Comment: Probably a dumb suggestion, but have you tried clearing Chrome's cache on Android?

Comment: Tried in incognito mode but no success.

Comment: Ok. I visited your site on my phone (LG G6 running Android 8.0) using both Firefox and Chrome (version 72.0.3626.121) and here's what I found (applies equally to both browsers): In portrait mode, the social media icons are not present in either state. However, in landscape mode, the social media icons are there, and behave, I believe, the way they should (inverting between black and white on toggle). If this is right, the problem has to be somewhere in your browser.

Comment: In tried in landscape it is working perfectly (didn't know it before). But it would work the same on the portrait as well. Well, there are images but they are transparent for some reason.

Comment: You're right. I can see them in dev tools (even the image pops up in the dev window), but they're invisible on the page. Very strange... I'm searching for the cause.

Comment: Found it. In your media query at `(max-width: 480px)`, one of the attributes specified is `display:flex;`. When this is disabled, the images reappear. However, the page position does move up slightly (maybe 10px). This may not be the full solution, but it is definitely at the root of the problem.

Comment: I feel stupid. Thanks a lot @ChristopherBennett

Comment: No problem. I forgot to specify, this is for the div with `class="social"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the prefixed for webkit

```
.class {
    -webkit-filter: invert(1);
    filter: invert(1);
}
```

I always use https://autoprefixer.github.io/ to look up if extra vendor prefixes are needed for certain css

Comment: Already it is present. After the project is built prefixes are added.